# Google Family Link reports an error stopping supervision

Tags: google-family-link

I have just turned 13.  The "Google Family Link" parental-control software is installed on my device.  I tried to stop supervision. After waiting for the mandatory 24-hour delay to elapse, it said error stopping supervision. What do I do?

Comment: I don't know.  However:  Why do you want to stop supervision?